# sample.xcodeproj cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed. while opening the Xib file in Xcode interface builder

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, interface-builder, visual-studio-mac

I am developing an app in Xamarin using Visual Studio for Mac.

When I try to open a .xib (or any other interface builder file) in Xcode(8.3) interface builder for designing, I get the error

> sample.xcodeproj cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed.

Does anyone have solution to this?

[image: Here is the Popup I got form Xcode]

Comment: Having the same problem. I have just updated Xcode & Visual Studio.

Comment: @vrwim I am having the latest version of Xcode (8.3.1)  and Visual studio(Preview 6)

Comment: Copy pasted your question on the forums https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/93633/project-xcodeproj-cannot-be-opened-because-the-project-file-cannot-be-parsed-error/p1?new=1

Comment: A colleague just informed me that a new update is available that fixes the problem for him. Trying now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio for Mac Preview 8 (7.0 build 2845) fixes this problem.

Comment: I downgraded to Xcode 8 and Visual Studio for Mac Preview 3, It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem was in Info.plist file. Some of the mandatory fields that are empty cannot be parsed when trying to open a .xib file. And in my case *Minimum system version* field somehow happened to be empty.