# Xamarin.iOS MvvmCross template; can't open storyboard

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, visual-studio-mac

I get the following error when I attempt to open a storyboard for a project I created from the "MvvmCross Single Page Native Application" template:

"Project /Users/username/Desktop/MyProject.iOS/obj/Xcode/0/MyProject.iOS.xcodeproj cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed."

Everything works fine if I use any of the iOS app templates.

I'm running the following environment:

Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac (Preview)
Version 7.4 Preview (7.4 build 1026)
Installation UUID: d672627e-29b7-49bc-8b23-bb090208de99
Runtime:
    Mono 5.8.0.127 (2017-10/1eac626536b) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
    Package version: 508000127

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 11.8.0.20 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 1c6f300e
Branch: d15-6
Build date: 2018-02-07 23:42:40-0500

I'm running preview so that I can target Android 8.1 for another project but I was having the same issue with the stable release.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Visual Studio to `Preview 8` , it should can solve the problem.

Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494284/sample-xcodeproj-cannot-be-opened-because-the-project-file-cannot-be-parsed-whi).

Comment: I am actually running the latest preview available on beta (7.4 build 1026) as opposed to (7.0 build 2845) mentioned in the post from last April. Not sure how to get (7.0 build 2845) to try it out, is it alpha channel?